# TES Construction Set - Import an external mod?

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind, the-elder-scrolls-construction-set

I am using the Morrowind version of The Elder Scrolls Construction Set, and I have a mod that was downloaded from elsewhere. I would like to see how this mod was made, so I can make my own,  so I wanted to open it. It wasn't in the Open list, and I can't figure out how to import it specially. It is a `.esp` file like all the others, so why can't I open it?
**EDIT:** Please do not answer or vote. I am working on moving this to GameDev, but there is currently a comment that could solve my problem. Please comment if you can help, but keep in mind this post will probably be deleted.

Comment: (1) Is it a Morrowind mod? Oblivion and Skyrim also use .esp files, and each game has its own Construction Set/Creation Kit. (2) If it is a Morrowind mod, do you have it in the 'Data Files' directory?

Comment: @Glasseyed Does it have to be in the Data Files directory? And yes, it is a Morrowind mod.

Comment: It's been a while since I modded Morrowind, but if memory serves, the CS won't look elsewhere. I've been able to avoid the Steam version, so I don't know if that's different.

Comment: @Glasseyed OK. Thanks. I'm going to delete this later, so please don't answer or vote.

Comment: Too bad I can't answer. I've done what you are asking by simple starting the construction set and then I load the main .esm file (Morrowind.esm) plus the mod file (Example.esp). Of course, if the mod is in Data folder it will be displayed in the list. If your mod has other dependencies (say Bloodmoon) you have to load those files Morrowind.esm, Bloodmoon.esm and finally Example.esp. I've opened mods and created mods from others mods before by doing this.

Comment: @Ethan It was probably a bad .esp. ASCIIThenANSI, how's the moving going?